# Div section in HTML won't show up on webpage

Tags: html, class

I am using the following HTML code on a webpage hosted by virb.com. It is not showing up when I save and open it in the browser.

```
<div src="squares" alt="">
  <a id="Donate" href="http://caase.org/donate">
    <img src="http://media.virbcdn.com/files/ac/c2ce1904ee83a1cc-DONATESQUARE.jpg" alt="" style="padding: 3px;" />
  </a>
  <a id="EndDemandIL" href="http://www.enddemandillinois.org/">
    <img src="http://media.virbcdn.com/files/14/5da8029b39657647-EndDemandSquare.jpg" alt="" style="padding: 3px;" align="left" />
  </a>
  <a id="Subscribe" href="http://caase1821.blogspot.com/">
    <img style="padding: 3px;" src="http://media.virbcdn.com/files/20/4f7cdbe9914c6a0a-CAASEBlog.png" alt="" align="left" />
  </a>
  <a id="Subscribe" href="http://www.enddemandillinois.org/subscribe">
    <img style="padding: 3px;" src="http://media.virbcdn.com/files/25/3902f908371033be-Subscribebutton.jpg" alt="" align="left" />
  </a>
  <br style="clear: both;" />
  <p>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="stretch"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong style="font-size: 14px;">&nbsp;</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5e9k2bw7/1/
Is there any css attached?

Answer (score 1):

My browser assembles your great layout, just fine!